# How to ask for authentication before connect to devices using bluetooth?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, pairing

I want to make demo application, which contains following features.

1. search and show device list in my device Bluetooth range.
2. connect(pair) selected devices.
3. then share string data.

For doing that I am using core Bluetooth framework(Central and peripheral classes). using that I am able to search devices, connect devices and transfer string data also.

but I am not able to authenticate devices before pairing(when I call connect method it is directly shown me connected status). how is it handled in ios?

also please suggest me I am on the right path or I need to use another library to implement this functionality.

Comment: If your peripheral has a characteristic that requires encryption then iOS will prompt for pairing.  If not then it will just connect

Comment: @Paulw11, When we connect other android devices while connecting we ask for entering the code then it will connect. but here I can show the list of devices, and when I call connect method, it will show me directly connected. is this behavior of iOS or I am going wrong.

Comment: As I said, on iOS if the BLE peripheral doesn't require encryption then no pairing (actually bonding) is required to connect, the connection will just proceed.

Comment: @VinodJadhav: What is your target device?, Which is your target Bluetooth Version ? , Which Bluetooth profile is using for connect.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else beating their head against a wall, I have the solution to this issue. It's as simple as setting the AUTHENTICATION required flag for a characteristic on your BLE device. Once that flag is set, you need to attempt a READ from that service / characteristic using the iOS device. Once the read is requested, the BLE device will send back a failure message which then prompts iOS to display the PAIRING / BONDING popup. After that, you're golden.

Here is an example of a Cypress BLE device permission group. The settings are similar for most BLE embedded devices out there.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

yes it is possible to ask pairing request from BLE device to ios.

I followed below steps to make ios app to ask for pairing.

1. edited my ble app to return error code 'RBLE_ATT_ERR_INSUFF_AUTHEN' using gatt write response function.
2. attempted a write from ios app then i got a prompt to enter pairing key.
3. used the randomly generated pairing key by BLE device to pair.

Paulw11's comment also helped me to solve that problem,

Regards
Bharath GK